# Node.js/Express App - Changing source code does not change app

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

Firstly - sorry for the rather dodgy question title.  I've been trying to figure out how to explain what I'm experiencing and I couldn't sum it up with a catchy title.

Basically I'm just starting out playing around with Node.  I'm trying to put together a very simple node/express app.

Initially, everything was fine.  I set up a few routes and they all worked.  Except one, which errored.  It errored because of a typo.  Ooops.

Fixed the typo and tried to navigate the route in Chrome.  The error persisted.

I've cleared browser cache, restarted my machine and everything/anything else I can think of.  I've even deleted all the js and compiled again from typescript.  Nothing seems to work, no changes seem to make it into the app.

Hopefully this is a node newbie issue!

Tools:  Visual Studio 2013, Node.js Tools for Visual Studio and TypeScript

Comment: Suggests to me that the error is still in there, somewhere.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: @James - error definitely still isn't there.  The app is only about 25 lines at the minute!  As I said, I'm just playing around with node for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly an issue with one of the tools you are using, or perhaps a weird system setup. With native javascript you don't compile anything, so loading new server code just requires restarting the server--you never have to restart your machine (disabling browser cache is always a good idea though).  You should find where the javascript files are that typescript built, fix the typo there manually, then try running the server; perhaps without the involvement of your IDE (in case the plugin is buggy or just to reduce the range of possible culprits).

Comment: For some, unknown, reason uninstalling and then re installing Node.js Tools for Visual Studio seems to have solved the problem.